# I receive isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Tags: android, sockets, wifi-direct

I wrote an Android WiFi-Direct application, based on google example.

It works very well when the client phone the Samsung and the server is Xiaomi, but when I try to connect with the my Xiaomi to the Samsung server I receive the `WiFi socket failed java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 8040) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)` error message.

The WiFi-Direct connection is established, the toolbar icon appear, but I cannot create a socket.

The google sample application works in both way.

Any idea about what' s wrong?

Comment: Maybe the two phone always decide, whitch is the client and which is the server, and opposite order doesn't work.

Comment: I solved, both activity need both client and server task:

Comment: if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
 NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
 if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

Comment: mManager.requestConnectionInfo(mChannel,
    new WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener() {
     @Override
     public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo info) {
      p2pInfo = info;

Comment: if (info.groupOwnerAddress != null) {
       if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
        new ServerAsyncTask().execute();
       }
       else if (info.groupFormed) {
        new ClientAsyncTask().execute();
       }
      }
     }
    }
  );
 }
}